# Error while building catkin_ws in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm trying to install ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 13.10 from source and I get this error while builiding `catkin_ws` with `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y` :

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y gazebo2]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gazebo2
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y gazebo2] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [gazebo2]
```

Can someone point me out how can I get pass this dependency? (that means, how to make `rosdep` ignore `gazebo2` package)

Already tried `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y -r` (to ignore minor errors) but no luck.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129616/error-while-building-catkin_ws-in-ubuntu-13.10/) by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2014-02-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-03-20**:
Hi all,
I experienced the same problem and fixed it by first launching:

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb
> http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu
> saucy main" >
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'
>
> wget
> http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key
> -O - | sudo apt-key add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To check all the dependecies without running into errors durign their installation try `rosdep check` instead of `rosdep install`. You can also use this info to manually install any additional dependencies that come "after" gazebo2 manually (e.g. with apt-get).

Edit: It is also possible to locally mark a dependecy as met by adding a local rosdep source file with an empty entry for that dependecy, see https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/15.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-02-17**:
Already resolved! Thanks

**Comment by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on 2014-02-18**:
I had the same issue, but lots of missing dependencies. This one made my life a bit easier:

rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro | grep apt | grep -v gazebo2 | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs sudo apt-get install -y

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-18**:
There is also the -s (simulate) flag for rosdep install, but I'm not sure if it would error if a deb package is not found.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-18**:
And for completeness, I just found out that there is a way to locally mark dependencies as met.